# How can I get table space in Teradata?

Tags: sql, database, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have this question in Teradata

This is my database called 'ORION', my table called 'customers' so, when I made query the table for the entire month of January, for example, I get 800k records. Is there anyway to convert the output of 800k records to MB in Teradata? or know how much space that output is in megabytes

Example of the query

```
select
    count(*)
from (
        select * from ORION.customers where f_date = to_date('01-01-2023','MM-DD-YYYY')
) A
```

|  | Count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 800,000 |

Thanks for the help and corrections on my question

I made the query to know the total size of the table, but it isn't what I need

Comment: Write it to a new table and look at the size of that new table. You could also math it out to get an approximate `(<full table gb> * 800000)/<total record count>`. This all gets fuzzy anyway with BLC, Fallback, column compression, etc. anyway.

Comment: Define this space: Is it the actual perm space used in Teradata for storing the 800k records (including or excluding indexes, compressed or uncompressed) or the space needed to export to a file (CSV or other format)?